# kineticjs - show/hide canvas slow due event-listeners?

Tags: performance, canvas, kineticjs, listeners

I'm developing a web-app with kinetic. I have different 'views' Each view contains several layers. Each layerd holds Images/Groups/Shapes, but mostly images.

When showing a view, the other view will be hidden (obviously), and the view which shows gets contructed (images are getting created and added to assigned layer) if not done already to prevent a large pile of drawing in the beginning of the web-app

+View

| + layer

| | + shapes

| | + ..

| + layer

| + ...

...

As my project grows, i noticed lags when switching between views. So my search begon...

I thought 'maybe the large amount of images will cause the canvas to lag', so i replaced images that do not need to be on the canvas with an images placed in the DOM (div with background).

With both methods there is a moueUp event causing 200ms delay! The reference to the code in kinetic points to this method:

```
Kinetic.DD._endDrag = function (evt){ ... }
```

No drag events are set on the clicked object which cause the view change

When looking ate the full kinetic test-case there is another event; mouseMove which causes 300ms lag! The reference to the code in kintec points me to tis part:

```
that.content.addEventListener 
inside 
_bindContentEvents: function ()
```

commented whith:

```
/**
* begin listening for events by adding event handlers
* to the container
*/
```

What happens inside these function? Nothing, it's just idle... This is proven by creating a profile ate the time of changing the view. 95% of the CPU time is spent on being idle...

I'm stuck How can i get rid of this lag, which makes my web-ap snappy! (and this is on a desktop, it needs to be performing on mobile devices (tabs) as wel!!

Comment: We too have experienced "wackiness" with dragging related events.  Have you tried updating to Kinetic version 4.4?  Eric has reworked the drag system (read that as removed the dynamic drag layer--Yeah!).  Seems to be much better now.  Make sure you read the release notes because there are some breaking changes: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Change-Log

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to upgrade atm (from 4.3.3), but i run into some isues (as always when upgrading kinetic). I will report back if the upgrade succeeded